# SSL_do_handshake() Failed AWS EC2 Flask

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, ssl, amazon-ec2, lets-encrypt

So I have an EC2 (ubuntu) instance on AWS running a Flask app and a mysql server. 
I have a domain registered and I requested ssl certs from Let's Encrypt certbot. The problem is that when I try to access the website from my own browser (up to date chrome on win10 and up to date chrome recent android) I get an internal server error. Btw I use gunicorn and nginx. I checked the error.log file and this is what I found:
2023/12/27 02:29:45 [crit] 1360#1360: *786 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: [my own ipv4 address], server: 0.0.0.0:443
2023/12/27 03:15:31 [crit] 1360#1360: *808 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 212.102.40.218, server: 0.0.0.0:443

I have ports 443 open for https and 80 for http. The firewall is active and the necessary ports are open (idk if these are relevant). 
So if I do a sudo reboot this problem goes away for about 1-3 hours. I have seen other questions like this, but those only mention other clients with outdated stuff, which is not true for me.
Thanks for any advice in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. You have to open and close a new connection for every database query. Example:

import pymysql

db_config = {

'host': 'your_host',

'user': 'your_username',

'password': 'your_password',

'database': 'your_database',

'port': 3306

}

with pymysql.connect(**db_config) as connection:

with connection.cursor() as cursor:

sql = 'SELECT * FROM table;'

cursor.execute(sql)

res = cursor.fetchall()

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I might have found a solution. It's a bit embarrassing, but for the app secret key I forgot it as "dev" so I changed that to a secure one and hopefully it works now.
Update: it was not it. Still looking for answers.